# Inserting a carriage return into t()

Tags: emails

How can I put a carriage return into the drupal t() function in Drupal 6? I tried using `\n` and that didn't work, which seems to make sense after reading the [documentation for the function](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/t/6).

Comment: `t()` doesn't remove new line characters from the string it gets. What is exactly the problem you have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never had a usecase for that and no working Drupal 6 installation, but I assume your problem isn't `t()` related, more PHP related.

```
<?php

// This does not work!
echo '\n';

// This does work on UNIX!
echo "\n";

// This does work on Win!
echo "\r\n";
```

Hope this answers your question and helps.